# VB.NET Detect when an application is flashing in taskbar

Tags: vb.net, notifications

I've been searching it for hours and the only thing I can find is how I can make a .NET app flashing/blinking on taskbar.

I want to be notified when an application is flashing on taskbar.. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: No, it is not. Unless you are willing to spend a pretty big amount of time to come up with a very complex piece of software performing a dynamic image analysis of all the icons in the taskbar. All this by assuming that you are very experienced (what I am under the impression that is not the case) in .NET. Also note that this is not the way to ask here: you should have shown us some of the attempts you did.

Comment: My friend. It is possible indeed and I just got an example in VB6. Now I just need to convert it to .NET. Here it is https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=068830d950fec543&id=68830D950FEC543%21233. And next time don't come here doubting about the other users skills in .NET, that's a bit rude. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi my friend (sorry for the delay, yesterday I left right before you wrote your last comment). After quickly skimming through your VB code, I am afraid that this code does NOT deliver what you requested (as I understood it; pretty clear from my comment above): knowing whether something "flashes"/"blinks" on the taskbar (involving the aforementioned complex image analysis). It does only take care of active/inactive windows (1000 times easier, as this small code proves)...

Comment: ... Next time, please, post a proper question explaining clearly what you want (or understand properly the answers/comments = I was clearly assuming that you meant blinking/flashing by looking at the icons; not at what is provoked by active/inactive windows). PS: You are right on the "doubting about the other users skills"; and I apologise about that. Note that (, unfortunately,) I have dealt with quite a few people here whose only motivation seems to be wasting others's time. Also note that it was a safe assumption from your question as I understood it (= aiming what is close to impossible).

Comment: PS: if what you want is converting this code to VB.NET, it should be pretty straightforward: just create a new VB.NET project, paste all this code in and correct the errors (not too many and VS would certainly help). But, please, update your question/title to show clearly what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.

Maybe my question was not clear enough but this code that I showed to you it's what I want and more. When an app starts flashing on taskbar it notifies you adding an item on the listbox.

[Code Example](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=068830d950fec543&id=68830D950FEC543!233)

Thanks for helping.